# Nothing show when run the project in Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

Good Day!

Need your help guys, I tried to run a basic project in Xamarin Visual Studio. I put a Button and Label on the App but it doesn't show when the project is executed. Pleas refer to the image below:

VS: 2015
Xamarin: 13

[here you go:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHUuP.png)

Comment: And your MainActivity.cs file how does it look?

Comment: Thanks Sir. Already solved the problem by removing the comment in mainactivitiy.

Comment: SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);